# insert into a list of pointers c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, copy-constructor

I'm trying to go over a list of Movie instances, and add one of them to a list of Movie* which is inside Worker class. problem is, when i try to print out this movie from the WorkerClass, mean to go over the Movie* list of Worker class, it prints garbage.

```
void MovieIndustry::addWorkerToMovie(string code, int id) {

Worker* toBeAdded;
Movie movieToAdd;

    for (std::list<Worker*>::iterator it=workers.begin(); it != 
    workers.end(); ++it)//look for Worker
    {
            toBeAdded = *it;

            for (std::list<Movie>::iterator it2=movies.begin(); it2 != 
            movies.end(); ++it2) //look for movie

            {
                if( it2->getCode() == code)
                {
                    movieToAdd = (*it2);
                    it2->addWorker(*toBeAdded); //Works
                    (*it)->addMovieToWorker(movieToAdd);
                }
            }//end for



        } //end for
}
```

Trying to print a movie from the list in Worker.cpp, it gives me:

```
void Worker::printWorkersMovies() const {

std::list<Movie*>::const_iterator movitt;

if(getNumOfMovies() >> 0)

{
    for (movitt=moviesOfWorker.begin(); movitt != moviesOfWorker.end(); 
    ++movitt)
    {

        std::cout << "length is" << ( (*movitt)-> getLength() ) <<std::endl;
    // IT PRINTS OUT length is: 943829758935781957
    // even though I inserted length = 2 
    }

}
```

}

Copy constructor of Movie, even though i wrok with pointer:

```
Movie::Movie(const Movie& toCopy) {

code = toCopy.getCode();
name = toCopy.getName();
length = toCopy.getLength();
year = toCopy.getYear();
rate = toCopy.getRate();
preview = toCopy.getPreview();
}
```

My method of adding a movie to Worker instance:

```
void Worker::addMovieToWorker(Movie& toAdd){

moviesOfWorker.push_back(&toAdd);

}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code: "I'm trying to go over a list of Movie instances, and add one of them to a list of Movie*" .. well, you cant, because `Movie` and `Movie*` are two different types and I am almost sure that the problem with your code is related to this confusion of objects with their memory adress

Comment: The way you are adding items to the list looks to be the problem as you.  You need to provide an [mcve]

Comment: ^ the key word being "Minimal".  Also, please properly format your code.

Comment: addMovieToWorker(Movie& toAdd) expects a reference. You are passing it a ref to a local variable Movie movieToAdd which memory is no longer valid at the end of the addWorkerToMovie method scope

Comment: I editted it to be more simple code.. please take a look now.
@Oualid how do i need to pass it then ?? because it doesn't compile if i do it elsewhere

Comment: Change void Worker::addMovieToWorker(Movie& toAdd) to void Worker::addMovieToWorker(Movie* toAdd) and store pointers. ie. (*it)->addMovieToWorker(*it2);

Comment: I can send an iterator to a function ? are you sure? because its type it iterator not Movie*.. isn't it?

Comment: My bad i overlooked *it2 type which is Movie and not Movie*. If you modify addMovieToWorker as i suggested you can call it like this (*it)->addMovieToWorker(new Movie(*it2)); Be sure to delete movie instances in the Worker destructor

Comment: it works right now. Thank you @oualid!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding pointers to automatic storage to your list.  As soon as `addWorkerToMovie` returns, `movieToAdd` is destroyed, but you still have a pointer to the memory that it used to be in.  The behavior when you later use that pointer is undefined, but in your case your program has re-used that memory for something else, and it just so happens to have stored `943829758935781957` where your movie's length used to be.

To make this work, you need to store pointers to objects that will still exist when you need to use them later.  It looks like your `Worker` class has a list of `Movie`s, so you may be able to store a pointer to one of those, instead of making a copy.  If not, you may need to dynamically allocate your objects using `new`, in which case you'll need to make sure to `delete` them when you're done with them.

Comment: ok, so I need to get a pointer instead of Movie& toAdd ? because i heard its complicated to get pointer as an argument.. I still do not understand which lines I need to change and how..

Comment: No, you need to store pointers to objects that will survive until you need them.  I've updated my answer to have a bit more info.

Comment: question is, I want Movie* of Worker to point to the list of Movies in MovieIndustry.. using @oualid's solution, which works- addMovieToWorker (new Movie(*it2)) , will I make a new copy of Movie ? because I don't want that to happen anyways.

Comment: Yes, that makes a copy.  You can do `addMovieToWorker(&*it2)` to add a pointer to the object in the `Worker`'s list.  Be warned that some containers may move their contents around when you do certain things to them, in which case pointers to their contents will become invalid.  I believe `std::list` is stable, but other containers such as `std::vector` are not.

Comment: and if I did made a new Movie(*it2) which is titanic, and then I would have changed titanic, would it change it both Worker Class and the main class (MovieIndustry) or it would change only if the main class?

Comment: When you alter an object, you only alter that object.  Any copies created are independent of their original, and will not be altered if the original is changed.